# make variant constructors public in .mli

Tags: ocaml

Consider `something.ml`:

```
type some_type =
  | This
  | That
```

Then, I can implement `main.ml` like this:

```
let x = Something.This
```

I want to create `something.mli` and keep the same functionality in `main.ml`. My first attempt was to write `something.mli` as:

```
type some_type
```

I thought that would make the variant constructors publicly available, but it didn't and now `main.ml` doesn't compile. Is there a way to expose the variant constructors in the `.mli`?

Answer (score 2):

The .mli files define the interface for a module all on their own and the .ml file is not used at all when compiling them. You actually can have a .mli file for a pack made out of multiple .ml files. The never magically pull something from the .ml file into the interface.

Now, same as in the .ml file, there are three ways to specify a type in the .ml file:

1) As an abstract type. Nothing is exposed of the type:

```
# type some_type;;
type some_type
# let v = This;;   
Error: Unbound constructor This
# let to_int = function This -> 1 | That -> 2;;
Error: Unbound constructor This
```

This hides the details of the type from the outside allowing the module to change the type at will later without breaking any source code. It is also used for phantom types that have no values or external values (see interfacing with C in the manual) that aren't ocaml types.

2) As public type. The structure of the type is exposed and values can be created:

```
# type some_type = This | That;;
type some_type = This | That
# let v = This;;
val v : some_type = This
# let to_int = function This -> 1 | That -> 2;;
val to_int : some_type -> int = <fun>
```

This is the opposite of the first case. Everything is made public.

But there is a third option:

3) As a private type. The structure of the type is exposed but values can not be created:

```
# type some_type = private This | That;;
type some_type = private This | That
# let v = This;;
Error: Cannot create values of the private type some_type
# let to_int = function This -> 1 | That -> 2;;
val to_int : some_type -> int = <fun>
```

This is somewhat between 1 and 2. The use case for this is when you need to control the construction of values. For example consider a type that holds small integers less than 100. You would write:

```
# let make x =
      if x < 0 || x >= 100
          then raise (Invalid_argument "Out of range")
          else x;;
val make : int -> int = <fun>
```

You then write the .mli file as:

```
type t = private int;;
val make : int -> t;;
```

This ensures that values of type t can only be constructed using the make function. Anything expecting a type t will only accept a value of type t constructed by make. On the other hand anything expecting a type int will also accept a value of type t. The later would not be the case with an abstract type.

Comment: This was a really helpful answer — I'd, personally, completely forgotten about `private` variants. It's not mentioned in the answer, but worth noting, that the *purpose* of this, is to allow consumers to do pattern-matching over the variant-type, without allowing construction of it.

Answer (score 1):

The something.mli file gives the interface for the something.ml file. So anything you want to be visible in the interface has to be defined in something.mli.

Since you want `This` and `That` to be visible, they have to be defined in something.mli.

For your small example, something.mli would contain exactly what you show for something.ml above:

```
type some_type = This | That
```

In a more realistic example, of course, the interface would contain much less than the implementation. In particular it just has the types of public functions and not the code.